# How to save image from webpage in R

Tags: r

I'm working with data such as [this](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/expert/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCDC/.ERSST/.version3b/.anom/T/%28Jun-Aug%201951%29/%28Jun-Aug%202009%29/RANGE/T/4/boxAverage/T/12/STEP/dataset://name//tryts/def/grid://name//T/def//fullname/name/cvntos/def//long_name/fullname/def//units/%28month%29/def/16/Mar/1951/ensotime/12/16/Mar/2009/ensotime/:grid/variable://name//ts/def//missing_value/NaN/def/grids:/T/:grids/values:/4.726814/17.71261/16.8054/7.672571/9.582948/16.15736/6.969452/9.551518/6.523163/11.81793/12.86575/9.082851/7.668276/7.420767/2.574668/18.23364/12.16573/11.85706/2.511509/16.94833/22.66705/6.30223/14.86728/6.776397/14.11806/17.05079/14.52353/19.8881/6.961097/16.6801/7.593886/8.260901/10.39524/16.77419/8.12265/21.63307/12.1125/15.79476/14.82236/10.11022/11.27425/6.595426/15.40595/13.99253/12.57994/21.15755/15.06527/21.02526/14.58289/27.06807/19.40745/7.534193/11.10381/14.45579/17.27443/10.67534/14.72511/26.0895/4.820548/:values/:variable/:dataset/.ts/T/2/index/.T/replaceGRID/%5BT%5Dcorrelate/correlationcolorscale//color_smoothing/null/def/DATA/-0.75/0.75/RANGE/X/Y/fig-/colors/%7C/contours/solid/thick/black/coasts/-fig/zlev/last/plotvalue+.jpg?plotaxislength=880). The url encodes all the code needed to make the map.

I want to loop through 90 of such plots and save them to my local disk from the website. I know how to construct the urls in R, but I don't have the first idea on how to save the image from RStudio.

Any ideas appreciated,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks scoa, figured it out for my machine by changing the method:

```
download.file(url,destfile="myimage.jpg",method='curl')
```

Comment: This method worked on Windows 10 with R-4.1.2

Answer (score 5):

You can use `download.file`:

```
download.file("http::/path/to/img",destfile="myimage.jpg")
```

This solution doesn't seem to work on Windows. Tested on linux with R 3.2.3

Comment: How does the resulting saved image look to you? (For me, it's a mess.)

Comment: It looks fine with the OP's example image, which url I did not include in my answer because it is too long.

Comment: Good to know. I'm on Windows, running R-3.2.3, and what gets downloaded looks like a messed up old TV test pattern.

Comment: I'm running the same and it's a big mess, suggestions?

Comment: you could also try `mode = "wb"`.